# How can I put spaces in my VBA project name?

Tags: vba, excel-addins

I have an Excel add-in I wrote in VBA, let's call it `MyAddin.xlam`.
I have set the project name as `MyAddin`.

When I open a second project and choose `Tools->References...`, MyAddIn appears just fine. Everything works. That's great.

But.. for purely aesthetic reasons, I would like the listing to appear as `My Addin` in the list of References.
Pretty much everything available in the list of potential References has spaces in the name.
But if I try to rename my project to have a space in the name, VBA doesn't allow me to do that.

So, silly as the question may sound, is there any way I can get spaces into the displayed name of my VBA add-in in the "References" list?

I'm perfectly willing to accept the answer "This isn't possible in VBA; you can only put spaces in the reference name if you build the add-in with another language", but I'm wondering if I am missing something simple.

Thanks!

**EDIT, Addendum:** Essentially, my question is: Is there a way to get the "displayed name" to be different from the project name, which doesn't care about filenaming/object naming restrictions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup you are right. VBA will not let you insert spaces in the Project Name in the Properties window.

If you try to, it will give you an error (see snapshot)

[image]

Well No Luck with VB.net as well. I added the space and it converted it to an underscore in Excel. let me test it more and get back to you...

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**FOLLOWUP**

Phew Finally! Yes it is possible in VB.Net. Let me know if you want more details?

[image]

Comment: But, essentially, my question is: Is there a way to get the "displayed name" to be different from the project name, which doesn't care about filenaming/object naming restrictions?

Comment: One moment.. testing it in VB.Net. I never tried it earlier :)

Comment: Does your VB.NET answer translate into VBA? I'm working in Excel here, not Visual Studio.

Comment: `"This isn't possible in VBA; you can only put spaces in the reference name if you build the add-in with another language"` I am essentially answering this question. You cannot do it in VBA but you can in Dot Net. And both are pretty similar (VB.Net is more advanced). You can develop for Excel From Visual Studio.

Comment: Well, I am certainly curious, for closure's sake, how you did it. But this project won't be involving Visual Studio.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11438/discussion-between-josh-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: Sorry had stepped out for couple of hours... Sure I can explain it. But before I do, let me quickly check if if you are familiar with VB.Net?

Comment: since this is outside the scope of the original question, please click on the chat link in my previous comment. You can break it down in the chat room. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can vary the display name as it appears in the Add-ins window by editing the `Title` Built-in Document Property, but that doesn't help you with the name in the References window

The VBE won't let you use illegal characters in a project name of module name, but that doesn't mean it can't be done.

For example, the Analysis Toolpak - VBA add-in `ATPVBAEN.XLAM` has a project name of `atpvbaen.xls` which includes the *supposedly* illegal character `.`

Likewise, the same project has a module called `VBA Functions and Subs` which includes the illegal   (space) character.

But the public procedures in Analysis Toolpak are still callable by using square brackets.

```
Sub test()

  'Run the auto_open macro in Analysis Toolpak
  [atpvbaen.xls].[VBA Functions and Subs].auto_open

End Sub
```

So Microsoft knows how to use illegal characters in project and module names, which is presumably done in the binary or with a special build of VBE.

**EDIT**

I just edited the binary of a VBA project and was able to put spaces in the VBA project name!

Interestingly, you can't export and then reimport the modules from Analysis Toolpak, as VBE still enforces the naming rules on import. Good luck getting that to work with Source Control.

**EDIT: 3 FEB 2017**
From the VBA file format spec: [MS-OVBA]

> [module name] **SHOULD** be an identifier... **MAY** be any string of characters... **MUST** be less than or equal to 31 characters long.
>
> [project name] **SHOULD** be an identifier... **MAY** be any string of characters... **MUST** be less than or equal to 128 characters long.

So it seems the VBE is imposing the *SHOULD* rule, but VBA is actually more permissive, if you are able to edit the project binary.