# Selecting custom reference name for a .NET (COM) tlb library when exposing it for VBA add reference dialog

Tags: c#, vba, excel, interop, com-interop

What I have is a C#, .NET 4.5 `ComVisible(true)` library that is being consumed by an Excel 2010 VBA client.

I have two questions:

1 -

In VBA when I add a reference to my tlb from "Tools -> References" I get the "Available References" dialog which displays my library reference name as the same name of my .tlb file but without the extension. If my .tlb file has a space, then it will be replaced with an underscore in the dialog.

The following thread discusses a similar issue, but from a VBA project point of view:
[How can I put spaces in my VBA project name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10655406/how-can-i-put-spaces-in-my-vba-project-name)

> **From my C# project, how can I control the name that will appear in "Available References"
>   (including using spaces)?**

[image]

2 -

With regards to the namespace of my library, how can I choose a namespace that is independent from my reference name and my .tlb name? e.g:

```vba
Dim oMyTest As New MyCustomNameSpace.MyTest
```

I have tried the following in C#, but it didn't work, it was always picking up the .tlb filename as the namespace:

```c#
[ProgId("MyCustomNameSpace.MyTest")]
public class MyTest: IMyTest
```

> **What do I need to change in C# to control my namespace within VBA?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conversion from assembly to type library is described in detail in this [MSDN Library section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xk1120c3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  The "Exported Assembly Conversion" article has the relevant details that you are asking about.  Quoting them:

> Assembly names often contain periods, which are not permitted in type library names. The export process converts periods in the name field of an assembly to underscores.
>
> The export process copies the AssemblyDescriptionAttribute if applied to an assembly at design time, to the helpstring or DocString associated with a type library. Neither the HelpFile field nor the HelpContext field in the type library is set. None of the LIBFLAGS in the type library is set.

Note that the [assembly:AssemblyDescription] attribute in ASsemblyInfo.cs uses an empty string by default.  You can edit it directly or use Project + Properties, Application tab, Assembly Information button.

Comment: Thank you, question 1 worked! Any idea about question 2? I didn't find a solution in the MSDN documentation.

Comment: COM doesn't have any notion of namespaces.  You can only use the typelib name.

Comment: What I meant by "namespace" is the prefix before the class name, in my example MyCustomNameSpace which is kind of namespace even though it is not called so.